# Nondegenaracy of differential mapping for differmorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\Psi : U_p \to (-\delta,\delta)^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $ be a differmorphism, the differential mapping is defined as
$$
 D \Psi = \left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial \Psi_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial \Psi_2}{\partial x_1} \\
\frac{\partial \Psi_1}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial \Psi_2}{\partial x_2}
\end{matrix}\right).
$$

It is always needed to verify the nondegeneracy of differential mapping for $ \Psi $ to be a differmorphism. On the contrary, given a differmorphism $ \Psi $, how can we prove that $ D \Psi $ is nondegenerated?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a diffeomorphism $\Psi$ you have that there exists a smooth inverse $\Psi^{-1}$ and so we have that $D\Psi \circ D\Psi^{-1}=D(\Psi\circ \Psi^{-1})=D(Id)=Id =D(\Psi^{-1}\circ \Psi)=D\Psi^{-1}\circ D\Psi$.

Comment: $ D \Psi \dot D \Psi^{-1} = I $ should be based on the assumption that $ D \Psi $ is nondegerated since we need the Cramer formula to prove the identity. The key point i would like to know is how can we give $ \vert D \Psi \vert \neq 0 $ from the existence of differential mapping of $ \Psi^{-1} $?

Comment: I just used the chain rule .

Comment: what is the definition of $ D\Psi^{-1} $?

Comment: Is just the differential of the inverse .

Comment: I get lost in the Cramer formula, thank you for the tips!